# How to use JCMD to access NMT data

Tags: jvm, native, jboss7.x, jcmd

I am trying to access NMT using jcmd trough this below code:

```
jcmd 4348 VM.native_memory [summary] [scale=10 GB]
```

But getting this below error:

```
com.sun.tools.attach.AttachNotSupportedException: Unable to attach to 32-bit pro
cess running under WOW64
        at sun.tools.attach.WindowsVirtualMachine.openProcess(Native Method)
        at sun.tools.attach.WindowsVirtualMachine.<init>(WindowsVirtualMachine.j
ava:56)
        at sun.tools.attach.WindowsAttachProvider.attachVirtualMachine(WindowsAt
tachProvider.java:69)
        at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.attach(VirtualMachine.java:208)
        at sun.tools.jcmd.JCmd.executeCommandForPid(JCmd.java:147)
        at sun.tools.jcmd.JCmd.main(JCmd.java:131
```

)

Comment: Use `jcmd` from the same JDK as the target process runs.

Comment: I have been using the same jdk.

Comment: Obviously not, because the above message is printed only when trying to attach a 64-bit jcmd to a 32-bit target JVM.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [jattach32](https://github.com/apangin/jattach/releases/download/v1.5/jattach32.exe) binary from [jattach](https://github.com/apangin/jattach) project.